# R: subset dataframe by two conditions based on one column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing locations (`loc`), where each location has two zones (`type`) and area of disturbances in each zone (`area`). From my dataframe, I would like to keep locations that have disturbances in both zones.

I thought I can simply do this by subsetting data by two conditions, however using AND condition (&)

```
subset(dd, (dd$type == "npr" & dd$area > 0 ) & (dd$type == "buff" & dd$area > 0 ) )
```

gives me null output

```
[1] loc  type area
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

and using "OR" condition (|)

```
subset(dd, (dd$type == "npr" & dd$area > 0 ) | (dd$type == "buff" & dd$area > 0 ) )
```

is not what I want..

```
  loc type area
1   a  npr   10
2   a buff   20
4   b buff   10
5   c  npr    5
7   d  npr    5
8   d buff    5
```

**How to correctly subset locations which have disturbance area > 0 in both zone types?**

---

My dummy data:

```
loc<-c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d")
type= rep(c("npr", "buff"), 4)
area = c(10,20,0,10,5,0,5,5)


dd<-data.frame(loc, type, area)
```

---

Desired output:

```
loc type area
1   a  npr   10
2   a buff   20
3   d  npr    5
4   d buff    5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compute a grouped summary to achieve this. That is, you want
to find out for each `loc` if *all* of the `area`s in that location are > 0.
I have always found base R a bit awkward for grouped statistics, but here's
one way to achieve that.

First, use `tapply()` to determine for each `loc` whether it should be
included or not:

```r
(include <- tapply(dd$area, dd$loc, function(x) all(x > 0)))
#>     a     b     c     d 
#>  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then we can use `loc` values to index that result to get a vector suitable
to subset `dd` with:

```r
include[dd$loc]
#>     a     a     b     b     c     c     d     d 
#>  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

dd[include[dd$loc], ]
#>   loc type area
#> 1   a  npr   10
#> 2   a buff   20
#> 7   d  npr    5
#> 8   d buff    5
```

We can also put these steps together inside a `subset()` call to avoid
creating extra variables:

```r
subset(dd, tapply(area, loc, function(x) all(x > 0))[loc])
#>   loc type area
#> 1   a  npr   10
#> 2   a buff   20
#> 7   d  npr    5
#> 8   d buff    5
```

Alternatively, you could use [**dplyr**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/):

```r
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  group_by(loc) %>% 
  filter(all(area > 0))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   loc [2]
#>   loc   type   area
#>   <fct> <fct> <dbl>
#> 1 a     npr      10
#> 2 a     buff     20
#> 3 d     npr       5
#> 4 d     buff      5
```

Created on 2018-07-25 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 2):

I would reshape first:

```
loc<-c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d")
type= rep(c("npr", "buff"), 4)
area = c(10,20,0,10,5,0,5,5)
dd<-data.frame(loc, type, area)

library(reshape2)
dd_wide <- dcast(dd, loc ~  type, value.var = "area")
mask <- subset(dd_wide, buff > 0 & npr > 0)[["loc"]]
subset(dd, loc %in% mask)

# one line:
subset(dd, loc %in% subset(dcast(dd, loc ~  type, value.var = "area"), buff > 0 & npr > 0)[["loc"]])
```

Comment: Reshaping works fine here, but won't generalize well: what if there were 10 or 100 different `type`s to check?

Comment: Not really, could use apply/all `apply(subset(dd_wide, select= -loc), 1, function(x) all(x > 0))` for example to filter "loc"s.

Comment: Sure, but then you might as well have used `tapply()` to begin with and skipped the reshape.

Comment: I get it, but I would prefer to have it wide, because imo in this it case allows you to do sneaky things, eg `mask <- dd_wide$loc[(exp(rowSums(log(subset(dd_wide, select= -loc)))) > 0)]` (with no visible loop).